# Flex 3: Highlight (changing background) of some characters within a string

Tags: list, apache-flex, filter, flex3, highlighting

I'm implementing a contacts list in Flex 3, and I right now I already implemented the list filtering to display the results. However, I would like to highlight the matching characters in the results, is it possible to accomplish this? Example:

[image]

Comment: htmlText? http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_04.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2008/03/regexr_free_onl.html) library. Look [example](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) from gskinner. You can also use setTextFormat to change the format of some characters but with this approache you can't change the text background color. If you don't need to change background color and it's enough to just underline use text format or TextRange.

If you need the 100% solution just dig into a solution like [this](http://code.google.com/p/flexlighter/) or read [this](http://ntt.cc/2008/07/20/how-to-highlight-the-text-in-flex-with-full-source-code.html) older but nice post. Hope that gives you a idea where to start from.

Comment: Isn't there any other way to do it?

Comment: Sure! I added some more links that will help you to find a solution.

Comment: Did this help you? If this was helpful feel free to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To change the background color, just place your Label or Text object inside of an HBox.

```
<mx:HBox>
   <mx:Label text="{contact.name}"/>
</mx:HBox>
```

Then set the backgroundColor on the HBox, which you can reference as the Label#parent. Since you're creating a dynamic Contacts list, I'll assume you have them in an array and are looping over the array to check if the name matches

```
var currentContact:Label = myContactLabelsArray.getItemAt(i);
...
Container(currentContact.parent).setStyle("backgroundColor","Yellow");
```

However, setting styles this way can be expensive http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=styles_08.html